# LOG4NET Could not create Appender

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I recently migrated an application to a new server (Windows 2008 Server R2, SQL Server 2008 R2, Poweshell) and everything works except I get an error when trying to log to the database.

```
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Could not create Appender [ADONetAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.ArgumentNullException: CreateConverterInstance cannot create instance, converterType is null
Parameter name: converterType
   at log4net.Util.TypeConverters.ConverterRegistry.CreateConverterInstance(Type converterType)
   at log4net.Util.TypeConverters.ConverterRegistry.GetConverterFromAttribute(Type destinationType)
   at log4net.Util.TypeConverters.ConverterRegistry.GetConvertFrom(Type destinationType)
   at log4net.Util.OptionConverter.CanConvertTypeTo(Type sourceType, Type targetType)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.SetParameter(XmlElement element, Object target)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.SetParameter(XmlElement element, Object target)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Appender named [ADONetAppender] not found.
```

I have tried reducing the buffer size to 1 and have checked the connection string, but it does not seem to be that,

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried Googling for an answer but have not found anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems that the dll with the ADONetAppender is missing in the output directory of your solution. Make sure the Dll is there so you can use it in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in that issue finally I fixed it. The solution is `ADONetAppender` class should have a **Default constructor**.

I am confident that this error, `Could not create Appender`, occurs because it doesn't have a default constructor.